# Можно ли вставить шорткод в JS скрипт, расположенный в functions.php в теме WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

уже не знаю как искать решение на этот вопрос, попробовал несколько вариантов, которые хоть как то подходят, но не один не работает.
Есть код JS с массивом данных, в который нужно запихнуть шорткод. Сам же JS код находиться в файле functions.php и полностью рабочий. Но вот вставка шорткода не как не получает. Можно ли вообще это реализовать? Пример структуры:

```
function cri_javascript_in_header() {

    if ( is_page ( '2080' ) ) { 
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
.....
  const data = {
      'tabs1-1': [
        { title: 'Все', content: '[gamipress_achievements type="okantovka-2" link="no" columns="3" thumbnail_size="200" filter="no" search="no" current_user="yes" times_earned="no" steps="no" toggle="no"]' },
        { title: 'Круглые', content: '[gamipress_achievements type="okantovka-2" link="no" columns="3" thumbnail_size="200" filter="no" search="no" current_user="yes" times_earned="no" steps="no" toggle="no"]' },
        { title: 'Многоугольники', content: '[gamipress_achievements type="okantovka-2" link="no" columns="3" thumbnail_size="200" filter="no" search="no" current_user="yes" times_earned="no" steps="no" toggle="no"]' },
        { title: 'Маски', content: '[gamipress_achievements type="okantovka-2" link="no" columns="3" thumbnail_size="200" filter="no" search="no" current_user="yes" times_earned="no" steps="no" toggle="no"]' },
      ],
.....
  </script>
        <?php
    } 
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cri_javascript_in_header' );
```

Comment: `<?php echo do_shortcode(...); ?>`?

Comment: Увы не работает, это первое что я попробовал. Возможно там нужны какие то дополнительные символы или что то еще

То есть я делал так:
` const data = {
      'tabs1-1': [
        { title: 'Все', content: '<?php echo do_shortcode('[gamipress_achievements type="okantovka-2" link="no" columns="3" thumbnail_size="200" filter="no" search="no" current_user="yes" times_earned="no" steps="no" toggle="no"]'); ?>' },  `

Comment: Проверяйте валидность шорткодов. Как минимум, судя по [документации](https://gamipress.com/docs/shortcodes/), параметры, которые вы указали, отсутствуют в документации. Плюс включите отладчик и посмотрите, что он выдает

Comment: Проверил скрипт, оказывается такая вставка работает, но проблема в том, что шорткод формирует HTML структуру, и вот она уже вызывает ошибку. Тогда вопрос в том, как правильно вставить в массив html код, который формируется из шорткода?

Comment: @rusgeli
В общем могу дать вам ссылку на нужную страницу, чтоб можно было посмотреть, в чем там дело, так как и скрипт и выводимый html очень большие. 
Сам скрипт должен выводить табы внутри табов. Скрипту присвоил id="taby_baby" чтоб его можно было легко найти. Ссылка на страницу - https://cripta.today/account/?user=1&tab=magazin_63b67a74bcf6d